# Trouble with Classes and Functions more information inside

Tags: c++

I am sorry but I am not even sure what this would be called to search for the question and answers.

I have a class Function

```
cout  << "Fraction x, y(2), z(-5,-6), w(1,-3);" << endl;
Fraction x, y(2), z(-5,-6), w(1,-3);
//Initializing the Fraction class with X at default values
//Y with 2 as Numerator and default value, Z and W with their values.
cout   << "z = " << z << ", y = " << y << ",  z = " << z
<< ", w = " << w << endl;
```

My issue is how do I make the ***"cout << "z= " << z << endl;*** print out the fraction for z. How I have this made up is I could do ***z.output();*** and it would print out the function perfectly but if I would to just put z I would get an error because neither the program nor I know how to make this work. I am hoping it is a very simple fix. I tried to assign ***z = z.output()*** but that is not working due to different value types. So I changed them both to the type Fraction and it still is not working.

***I have to use that top program (main) as is and cannot modify it. I can only modify my own functions***

Thank you

Comment: Provide an overloaded `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Fraction&)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this (this is a *global* function; not a method in any particular class):

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Fraction& f)  
{  
    os << f.output();
    return os;  
}
```

I'm assuming that `output()` has a suitable return type. If not then you can always insert alternative code in the above function.

This is the idiomatic way: note that you return a reference to the passed stream to enable the *chaining* of `<<`.

Comment: I appreciate the help, What could I search to get more information on this because I understand what you have put just enough to get this to work but not well enough to feel comfortable.   Thank you

Comment: Without trying to sound dictatorial, just do as I say and watch the behaviour using your debugger. Microsoft have an article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx

Comment: @Juscallmesteve there is really not much more to say on the topic. If you want to convince yourself, search for "overloading the output operator"

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying. I just need to somewhat visualize how this works together and what each part of the puzzle means, for me to retain it long term. But thank you and I will google "Overloading the output operator".